# Не могу вычислить ошибку в SQL запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

Не пойму где именно ошибка в SQL запросе(СУБД MySQL):

Выдаёт:

```
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (buyer_name, buyer_phone, buyer_address, \n" +
    "      goods_id, goods_price, goo' at line 1",
```

Текст запроса:

```
    INSERT INTO order (buyer_name, buyer_phone, buyer_address, goods_id, goods_price, goods_amount, total, date) VALUES ("Владимир", "+7 (904) 596-5124", "Красная Звезда Дом 5 Кв 6", "1", "16160", "5","80800", "1589901110");
```

Сама таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `buyer_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `buyer_phone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `buyer_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `goods_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goods_price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `goods_amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: `order` зарезервированное слово, имя таблицы с таким именем всегда должно быть в обратных апострофах

Comment: Пробовали "1", "16160", "5","80800", "1589901110" без кавычек?

Comment: @Mike в точку! Спасибо!!!!!

Comment: @AzizUmarov, да, пробовал по-всякому